# HTML Encoding - XSS protection

Tags: html, web, angularjs

My general rule for web development is that the server encodes HTML tags in any user-generated input when it is first submitted to prevent XSS.

However recently someone suggested that instead of sanitizing the input on the server end, angular could do the sanitizing on the client side **when displaying**. So basically you are allowed to input HTML tags and they will make it into the database. When served back to the client they are still embedded but angular itself strips out the harmful ones.

I can not immediately see something wrong with that assuming angular encoding is foolproof.

Does anyone have experience with this in either way? Does anyone see an issue with the front-end solution?

Comment: I believe this is entirely a question of the business requirements. If you can guarantee you will never have any other client apps/sites accessing that database, then it probably doesn't matter. If you ever do have other clients, then your choice is likely dictated by whether that client expects pre-escaped HTML or expects to do the escaping itself. My personal impression is that when possible one should store a custom markdown format *that is not HTML* so that your markdown->HTML converter acts as a whitelist, rather than your escaper acting as a blacklist.

Comment: The angular santizer is not very configurable, for instance it will let through img tags with a local URL, not everyone may want that. The config you can do is global, you can't do much case by case.

Comment: See security stackexchange: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9415/filter-user-input-before-the-database-or-upon-display